# ЗапуститьПриложение() на сервере 1C под linux

Tags: linux, сервер, 1с

Есть пара пакетных команд, которые надо исполнить на стороне сервера 1с под линухом.

```
КодЗавершения_ = Неопределено;
Каталог_ = КаталогВременныхФайлов() + "DummyIBCf";
СоздатьКаталог(Каталог_);
Платформа_ = КаталогПрограммы() + "1cv8";
СтрокаКоманды_ = СтрШаблон(
    "%1 createinfobase File=%2; /Out /tmp/createinfobase.log",
    Платформа_,
    Каталог_,
);
ЗапуститьПриложение(СтрокаКоманды_, Каталог_, Истина, КодЗавершения_);
```

Или даже ещё проще `СтрокаКоманды_ = "echo ok";`

Только платформа никаких ошибок не выбрасывает, но команда не исполняется и код завершения не возвращается. Вручную от имени службы 1Ски всё выполняется, а вот программно нет. В отсутствии прав ли проблема, но где тогда...

Comment: Исполняйте свои пару пакетных команд под вендузом. Линукс не предназначен для такого извращения!